# iOS - Is it possible to make a phone call programmatically without showing the phone number?

Tags: ios

I know we can make a phone call programmatically on iOS, and it opens the phone app and display the phone number. Is there a way to hide the phone number or show something else instead of the phone number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a contact for it so it shows the name of the contact name instead of the phone number, but there is no possible way to actually hide the phone number the user is calling.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question but, can I write my own telephone program, like Skype can make calls to landline without using the iPhone's phone. They have their own UI.

Comment: I see what you mean, but still I don't think you can possibly hide the called number.

Comment: Skype can do that because the call is a VoIP call. They are most likely having the user call their VoIP service, and then their VoIP service finds the correct phone number to call and calls that. If you're interested in learning more about how to interface with a VoIP service, look into CallKit.

Comment: Thanks @AdamPro13 , I actually just want to hide the phone number, and maybe going the contacts way could be a short term solution. Creating a VoIP software would be overkill, and as you mention, I would have to create a VoIP service that calls the landline (or any other non VoIP number)..

Answer (score 1):

You can not display name programatically when calling, because iOS does not provide you any mechanism in which you can pass name with phone number. The only way is you have to first save phone number with your desired name as a contact into user's phone and after that make a call programatically.

Comment: OK I see. The only drawback to this is I think there will be a "permission popup" to ask for access to contacts.

Comment: That is true. You would have to have permission to access contacts. If my answer was helpful, please rate and checkmark my answer!